# How to reload a Flask app each time it's accessed

Tags: python, d3.js, flask

I have a flask app that is accessed using the `/get_data` endpoint and providing a number as an id (`127.0.0.1:55555/get_data=56`)

```
@app.route('/get_data=<id>') 
def get_vod_tree(id):
    ...
    return render_template('index.html')
```

It invokes a function that fetches some data under that id and creates one json file [static/data.json] with the collected data and then returns render_template('index.html').

In the index.html there is a call to ../static/data_tree.js which in turn reads the json file and outputs a visualization in the browser using d3.js.

When the app runs, I get the same output on the browser even when I use a different id and the json file changes. It only works if I reload the app and then access the url.

**My question is:** 
How can I make sure that multiple users get the different outputs according to the id or how can I reload the app when I hit the endpoint.

Afterthought: If multiple users are using the app then there is only one file created each time

Comment: How are you getting the data into index.html?

Comment: I don't understand your process. Why having a single file overwritten each time instead of keeping all data<id>.json and just passing `id` to the template ? The only reason I can see is because the data can change between successive calls, but then why not pass it directly to the template ?

Comment: @polku Yes the data changes but it's also collected using a python function that formats the fetched json data.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for the answers. It helped getting to the bottom of this. It works now like this:

```
@app.after_request
def apply_caching(response):
    response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'
    return response
```

So by disabling the cache the application can treat each request as unique.

Answer (score -1):

If you set `app.run(debug=True)` in your test/dev environment, it will automatically reload your Flask app every time a code change happens.

To reload the application when a static file changes, use the `extra_files` parameter. See [here](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/master/serving/).

Example code:

```
extra_dirs = ['directory/to/watch',]
extra_files = extra_dirs[:]
for extra_dir in extra_dirs:
    for dirname, dirs, files in os.walk(extra_dir):
        for filename in files:
            filename = path.join(dirname, filename)
            if path.isfile(filename):
                extra_files.append(filename)
app.run(extra_files=extra_files)
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9511655/4675937)

Comment: That doesn't include a change in the static file though. It looks like some caching mechanism is in place.

Comment: @case how are you calling the server?

Comment: I use http://127.0.0.1:55555/get_data=56 in the browser and the data is fetched from a URL on a test server.