# Python flask application not displaying generated html file for second time

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a Python flask application which takes input id's and dynamically generates data into a html file. Below is my app.py file.

```
@app.route('/execute', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def execute():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        id = request.form['item_ids']
        list = [id]
        script_output = subprocess.Popen(["python", "Search_Script.py"] + list)
        # script_output = subprocess.call("python Search_Script.py "+id, shell=True)
        # render_template('running.html')
        script_output.communicate()
        #driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        #driver.get("home.html")
        #driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('Executed').style.display = '';")
        return render_template('execute.html')

@app.route('/output')
def output():
    return render_template('output.html')
```

output.html file has below code at the bottom.

```
<div class="container" style="text-align: center;">
        {% include 'itemSearchDetails.html' %}
</div>
```

itemSearchDetails.html is generated every time dynamically based on the input. I check for different inputs and it is generating perfectly. When I run it with some input(assume 2) values for the first time, it runs perfectly and shows the output correctly. But, when I run for different values(assume 4) for the next time, the file 'itemSearchDetails.html' is generated for those 4 values but the browser only shows output for the first 2 values. No matter how many times I run it, browser shows only output with the first run values.

So, every time only the first inputted values are shown no matter how many times I run. I am not sure if it is browser cache issue since I tried "disabling cache" in chrome. Still it didn't work. Please let me know if there is something I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38371484/5167302):

Parameter `TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD`

> Whether to check for modifications of the template source and reload
>   it automatically.  By default the value is None which means that Flask
>   checks original file only in debug mode.

Original documentation could be found [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/config/).

Comment: Excellent. This worked. Flask now check and loads the template file every time. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Jinja is caching the `include`d template.

If you don't need to interpret the HTML as a Jinja template, but instead just include its contents as-is, read the file first and pass the contents into the template:

```
with open('itemSearchDetails.html', 'r') as infp:
    data = infp.read()
return render_template('execute.html', data=data)
```

...

```
{{ data|safe }}
```

(If you do need to interpret the HTML page as Jinja (as `include` will), you can parse a Jinja `Template` out of `data`, then use the `include` tag with that dynamically compiled template.)