# Force cache reload on Flask

Tags: caching, flask

There is a way to disable cache for a spacific page in flask? I have some problem working whit bootstrap-calendar that read data from json. If the calendar has cache data it will not update event. If i clean cache or use incognito mode i have no problem.
I have no idea on how to solve my problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reload Flask app when template file changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508667/reload-flask-app-when-template-file-changes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Flask doesn't use cache in such ways, it caches only static data if not specified. If a page has changed, flask will force the browser to reload new data instead of using cache. Any restart can kill all the cache used earlier, meaning that all users previously accessed the page will lost all their cache.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with your browser, rather than Flask.

If you're using Chrome you can open up Developer Tools > Network > Disable Cache. The cache will remain disabled for that specific page while Dev tools is open.

If I'm not  using Dev tools, I like to undock it in a separate window and then minimize it to keep my workflow clear.

Comment: This is not the solution. I cannot disable the cache of evryone that use my app.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508667/reload-flask-app-when-template-file-changes