# how to rewrite flask debug reload rules by myself?

Tags: debugging, flask

when using flask debug mode, i found it can only detect the code changes but cannot detected the related file contents changes. so i am trying to rewrite the debug rule so it can detect all the changes and Restarting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reload Flask app when template file changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508667/reload-flask-app-when-template-file-changes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `extra_files` parameter in `run` function and pass list of filenames to watch.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, extra_files=['config.env', 'config.yaml'])
```

See [werkzeug documentation](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.15.x/serving/#werkzeug.serving.run_simple) for more options.