# update flask without hard refresh

Tags: python, css, flask, jinja2

I'm new at flask and programing, and I want to ask is it possible to get browser update css without hard reset? because its very frustrating every time I change something go into browser and hit CTRL + F5.

```
from flask_web import app

if "__main__" == __name__:
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: What do you mean by hard reset? And what happens when you hit CTRL+F5?

Comment: CTRL+F5 resets whole page and re-upload data from server. if you just refresh page with out clearing cache nothing happens, but you can do hard reset and its works without clearing cache

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508667/reload-flask-app-when-template-file-changes

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT` to `-1` as follows.

```
app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = -1
```

It basically sets the `Cache-Control` header to an expiry in seconds. `-1` essentially disables the caching. The default is 12 hours or 43200. This header tells your browser when to reload individual assets.