# Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

Tags: python, heroku, flask

Can someone explain to me this error message on Heroku?  App works fine locally but has never succeeded online

```
heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python app.py ${PORT}`
app[web.1]:  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

The app itself is not very complicated

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static') 

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from os import environ
    app.run(debug=False, port=environ.get("PORT", 5000))
```

Answer (score 25):

You need to specify `host='0.0.0.0'` in `app.run()`. Unless told otherwise, Flask binds to "localhost", which means it won't bind to an externally visible interface.

See [Flask - configure dev server to be visible across the network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023052/flask-configure-dev-server-to-be-visible-across-the-network)

Comment: Deployed a pure Python server (http.server.HTTPServer) to Heroku, it also works! `0.0.0.0` instead of the usual `localhost` does the trick, thanks @bimsapi!

Comment: Saved me! thaks

Comment: Glad to know that this is a flask API specification, and not a problem with Heroku (or any other hosting provider for that matter) 