# Heroku Apps forever crashed with streamlit

Tags: heroku, streamlit

My first time deploying streamlit on Heroku, and the scripts are on [this GitHub](https://github.com/ianyu93/web_app_test). I'm actually deploying from local, so this is just to share my scripts to debug. The following is the error message.

```
2020-12-31T23:47:18.055589+00:00 heroku[router]: 
at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" 
method=GET path="/" host=stormy-dawn-49490.herokuapp.com
request_id=b3df4074-d363-41e5-8ecd-d101070679f7 
fwd="99.230.168.115" 
dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2020-12-31T23:48:01.327576+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> 
Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

I have four scripts, which is also linked to my GitHub repository the beginning of the question.

setup.sh

```
mkdir -p ~/.streamlit/
echo “\
[general]\n\
email = \”<dont@spam.us>\”\n\
“ > ~/.streamlit/credentials.toml
echo “\
[server]\n\
headless = true\n\
enableCORS=false\n\
port = $PORT\n\
“ > ~/.streamlit/config.toml
```

Procfile:

```
web: sh setup.sh && streamlit run app.py
```

requirements.txt:

```
fredapi==0.4.2
numpy==1.18.5
pandas==1.1.5
plotly==4.14.1
python-dateutil==2.8.1
python-slugify==4.0.1
Quandl==3.5.3
scikit-learn==0.23.2
streamlit==0.72.0
yfinance==0.1.55
gunicorn== 19.9.0
```

app.py: I'd suggest read [here](https://github.com/ianyu93/web_app_test)
I didn't put much in the app.py as I'm just trying how to deploy on Heroku

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. It's pretty hard to help with mystery code we can't see.

Comment: Though: "Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch"—have you tried to bind to the port given by the `PORT` environment variable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Heroku + node.js error (Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693192/heroku-node-js-error-web-process-failed-to-bind-to-port-within-60-seconds-of)

Comment: @MartinZeitler Unfortunately, it dosn't.

Comment: @Chris I'm going to edit the question now

Comment: @IanYu Your app needs to bind to `process.env.PORT` when deployed... which it obviously doesn't.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I included the codes for my setup.py. Would that not be enough?

Comment: It's nevertheless an exact duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65455211/549372

Comment: @MartinZeitler Thank you! The exact issue was actually as the code for setup.sh was copied, for somehow the double quotation was not recognized! I now am able to run it!

Comment: @MartinZeitler If you would post an answer, however, I'd love to select you as the solution

Comment: @IanYu I don't care much about reputation (just see my profile) and refrain from posting copy & paste answers. Instead, better upvote the one answer, which I've linked (that's how this site works).

Comment: @MartinZeitler will do!