# Unable to connect to Flask server from different devices on the same network

Tags: python, flask

Following the complete instructions on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023052/flask-configure-dev-server-to-be-visible-across-the-network/37204397#37204397) thread, I got my Flask server to work and it is now accessible through different devices, with my config file as follows:

```
#config.py
DEBUG="True"
UPLOAD_FOLDER="Reports/"
SECRET_KEY = "Supp0s3dT0B3Un1qu3AndS3cr3t"
```

with app.run() called as

```
app.run(host = '0.0.0.0', port = 7000, debug = True)
```

However, setting the SERVER_NAME variable in the config file as

```
SERVER_NAME = '0.0.0.0'
```

actually gave me an error and refused to connect as follows:

```
192.168.0.163 - - [13/May/2016 12:25:58] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404
```

However, when I removed it, only then did the server get accessed by my other device. I was accessing my machine through it's IP I found through ifconfig - 192.168.0.126:5000.
Any ideas why this happened?

**Note: app.run() was called the same way in both the cases.**

Comment: Nowhere in the thread you link someone put an ip in SERVER_NAME, because that's not what you're supposed to do, especially 0.0.0.0. You're supposed to put something like 'myapp'

Comment: @polku It is mentioned as a solution in the last answer! http://stackoverflow.com/a/35146471/4803814

Comment: Please include an error in your question that you are getting. Paste an image or copy paste all the traceback from console ?

Comment: @HassanMehmood Done! It was                                                             192.168.0.163 - - [13/May/2016 12:25:58] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Comment: Seems like you are giving wrong URL

Comment: @HassanMehmood I was accessing it using the IP of my host on the network. 192.168.0.126:5000. And even now, when I try to access it as 192.168.0.126:5000 or 0.0.0.0:5000 it gives me an error. However, when I change SERVER_NAME to 'nhm.dev:5000' and access it with this url, it works. So aren't IP addresses allowed in the SERVER_NAME variable?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, I have done this hundreds of time. May be an issue with your machine's settings, firewall or something else that blocking your call.

Comment: `SERVER_NAME` is used primarily for supporting subdomains, something that doesn't work with IPs. Do you even need to give it a value?

Comment: @dirn I was trying to debug it when I came across this snag. It is not required, but was just wondering why it went wrong.