# How to access python flask application in windows when running it in a linux container?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, networking, flask

I am working on a microservice written in python. My microservice works fine on my windows machine and I can easily test it. However, on my Linux container it may work fine too but I cannot test it. Even when optimizing my code for network access as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7027113/1987258).

So here is my microservice:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

-
I tested this by running on windows by typing in the command prompt:

```
python.exe app.py
```

-
I got a message ending with

> Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL C to quit).

To test my microservice, I executed my browser to access: 
http://localhost:5000/

I can see the "Hello World" message. So my application seems to work perfectly.

After that, I started working with docker. Here is my Dockerfile (named "Dockerfile").

```
FROM python
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential
RUN pip install Flask
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

Here is my build command:

```
docker build -t docktoflask .
```

Which shows some output considering the build process.

Then I started running the container with this command:

```
docker run -p 5002:5002 docktoflask
```

I got the same ending message as I got on windows (which is remarkable because I specified port 5002).

After that I tried testing with this link:
http://localhost:5002/

(of course I also tried http://localhost:5000/ )

No success.... (which means a browser error instead the hello world message). The error is in Dutch (my browser language) but means the same as [this](https://i0.wp.com/dowe.io/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Screenshot-from-2015-11-20-121543.png).

This is annoying because it seems to work and the port is really active.
There are two applications, I should be able to access from my browser (portainer and my own application). I can access portainer without any problems. How can I access my microservice, when running it in a docker container?

[image: my running containers]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command

```
docker run -p 5002:5002 docktoflask
```

means that the internal container port 5002 will be exposed as host port 5002 (localhost:5002), even if the internal container port 5002 is not opened yet.

You have to change this to

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 docktoflask
```

Comment: Thanks. "docker run -p 5002:5000 docktoflask" also works because 5002 is opened on the windows environment I am working on.