# Can you use Python to write cross-platform apps for both iOS and Android?

Tags: python, cross-platform, mobile-development

This question: [Is it possible to use Python to write cross-platform apps for both iOS and Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664196/is-it-possible-to-use-python-to-write-cross-platform-apps-for-both-ios-and-andro)

was asked about 7 years ago and I wanted to see if the general consensus on this has changed.

I need to make an app that utilizes portrait mode, which is most commonly written using python. However, I  need this to run on both IOS and Android platforms. Are there any cross platform frameworks that would be supportive of python for this function of the app?

Comment: The reason that the question hasn't really been asked since is that asking for software recommendations e.g. libraries is off-topic on Stack Overflow now. The latest answer on that thread is effectively the state-of-play

Comment: [This more recent answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53519266/python-and-dart-integration-in-flutter-mobile-application) could be of interest.

Comment: @roganjosh it's not a typical question, but stackoverflow says you can ask about "software tools used by programmers" source: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. If people can ask about their IDE's on here, I'm pretty sure it's appropriate to ask about a framework.

Comment: @roganjosh If i stand incorrect - where do you suggest I ask this question?

Comment: Asking about a problem with a particular IDE is not the same as asking "what IDE should I be using?" or "What IDE supports code-folding?". I'm not aware of any Stack Exchange site that is appropriate, it might be better on Quora or Reddit. However, as I said, the latest answer to the thread you linked is the current state of play. There's also Kivy.