# How can I run Python code in my Flutter app

Tags: python, flutter

I would like to know if it's actually possible to run python code inside a flutter app, locally. I need to blur faces an license plates (for anonymization reasons). I found this project https://github.com/understand-ai/anonymizer, which seems to be adapted to my need but I don't know if it's possible to run it inside my app. Or maybe you know other ways to do the same then I'm open to all the possibilities, but it must be free / open source.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python and Dart Integration in Flutter Mobile Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53519266/python-and-dart-integration-in-flutter-mobile-application)

Answer (score 0):

Vayhuit there isn't so much about running Python in Flutter as Flutter was designed to use Dart, however, here's a plugin that was designed to allow for the support of other languages in Flutter.

https://pub.dev/packages/starflut

Comment: First, thanks for your answer. I've read a tutorial about starflut (http://www.srplab.info/flutter/2018/07/29/flutter-and-python.html) and I'm confused about one part. What does the code below "compile for ios". Is it for make it runnable on IOs ? Or just run the app on an IOs emulator ?