# Running a flask application on a local network with a domain name?

Tags: flask

I am doing a side project of transitioning my companies inhouse accounting app to a flask based web site.

I was just testing today to see if I could deploy onto the local network for everyone to access, and that worked will enough however it was my computers local ip ie something like 192.168.1.212:5000.

Is there a way I can run the flask app off my computer and on my computers local network where they could go to something like ourcompanyapp.com and get the app?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023052/configure-flask-dev-server-to-be-visible-across-the-network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023052/configure-flask-dev-server-to-be-visible-across-the-network)

Comment: That question is how I got it up and running in the first place, now I just want the additional step of making it an actual domain name to type instead of an ipaddress:portaddress.

Comment: So how to deploy your flask app?

Comment: Strictly on a local network with a domain name, correct.