# How to access Virtualbox Python Flask service from host browser?

Tags: python, virtualbox

I have written a simple Python Flask application as follows:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World2'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=5000)
```

This code is then executed in my Virtual box Ubuntu 18.04 Server VM. It starts listening to port 5000 in my VM.

However, when I try to access it from my host browser at 127.0.0.1:6000, it is not loading.

I have enabled port forwarding in Virtualbox NAT port forwarding option as shown below:

[image]

**How to access the Flask server from host?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configure Flask dev server to be visible across the network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023052/configure-flask-dev-server-to-be-visible-across-the-network)

Comment: Configure the host to be `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably your application binds to loopback network interface.

Change it to bind to all interfaces so it is accessible from the outside:

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, port=5000)
```