# Dummy server name in flask development

Tags: python, flask, server-name

Is it possible to create a dummy server name in Flask during production? For example I want the following: `www.foo.com` for the development.

```
def main():
    app.run(debug=True, host='foo.com', port=8000)
```

such that routes like:

```
@app.route('/bar/')
def bar() -> str:
    return 'bar'
```

would be reached at `foo.com/bar/`.
I've tried changing the configuration:

```
app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'foo.com'
```

but I get an **OSError: [Errno 49] Can't assign requested address**

Answer (score 0):

change host parameter

```
app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

It defines the ip addresses the server will listen on, not the DNS. See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023052/configure-flask-dev-server-to-be-visible-across-the-network?noredirect=1&lq=1) for more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Add an entry for `foo.com` pointing to the local IP (127.0.0.1) in your development PC hosts file. For example, on Windows the hosts file is called `hosts` and is located at `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` for a standard installation.

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host


127.0.0.1 foo.com
```

You will then be able to server up your Flask pages on `foo.com:8000` when developing.