# Quick way to run flask on 0.0.0.0:80 in company's intranet

Tags: python, flask

I am noticing that the Flask default server should not be used for the production server.
However, in my case, I just want to share a prototype web application created by Flask in the company's intranet using port`80`.
I tried to specify port referring to [stackoverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023052/configure-flask-dev-server-to-be-visible-across-the-network) by the following code.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=80)
```

But they still run on `127.0.0.1:5000`. (refer to screen capture of command prompt)
  [image]
Does anyone know what I should revise in order to run the flask application using port 80?

Comment: Please check if there's another program using port 80 (e.g., apache, etc.). And the indentation is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to run it with

```
python <yourfile>.py
```

**flask run** might be a cause of your problem

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the Documentation, `flask run` will run the development server on `127.0.0.1:5000` and ignore your `app.run`:

> The run command will start the development server. It replaces the Flask.run() method in most cases.

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/cli/#run-the-development-server

So instead of using `flask run` just execute your script directly with Python.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to launch this using `flask run` is by specifying the `-h` flag:

```
flask run -h 0.0.0.0
```