# AWS Connection Refused on Port 8080

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, flask

I have an EC2 instance in which I am running a Flask server on port 8080.

```
* Running on http://0.0.0.0:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

I can run `curl` and get the response from my EC2 instance.

```
$ curl -X GET '0.0.0.0:8080/fbeac'
```

However, I cannot use the public IP/DNS to get the response and running

```
$ curl -X GET '3.135.62.118:8080/fbeac'
```

results in `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 3.135.62.118 port 8080: Connection refused`. I get the same error when I try to `curl` using my local machine.

My application is listening on port 8080, which I checked by running `netstat`.

```
$ netstat -an | grep 8080
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Moreover, I have ensured the Security Groups are set up correctly. I have experimented with just custom TCP port 8080, all TCP ports, and (currently) all traffic. I have also opened up HTTP/HTTPS ports on the side just in case, but with no luck.

This leads me to believe it might be a firewall issue but I am on an Amazon Linux machine and the default policy seems to be to `ACCEPT`, which I checked by running `iptables`.

```
$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Is there some other thing I should be checking or button I should be flipping?

My AWS Instance ID is `i-0080c730c4287ca3c`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023052/configure-flask-dev-server-to-be-visible-across-the-network

please ensure if you have this line app.run(host='0.0.0.0')

Comment: Yes, it is globally visible. If I run the same code locally, I can access it from other computers using my machines public IP.

Comment: Ok when you defined your VPC settings. Did allow it to be accessible via the Internet. As you said you have checked with Security groups
So that's the next thing to be checked.Can you check your VPC configuration as well

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest checking what access rules are defined in your EC2 instance [security groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-security-groups.html). You might need to open up port `8080`.

Also, as a side note, consider not using flask development server in production like that. It's fine for testing, but you really should be using something like uwsgi for production workloads.

Comment: I currently have the following 2 security groups (apart from SSH)

1. Custom TCP Rule    TCP    8080    0.0.0.0/0
2. All traffic    All    All    0.0.0.0/0

which I think should be sufficient.

Yeah, I am only using the Flask environment for testing for now.

Comment: Something is not right, this should work, which I just confirmed by spinning up a new EC2 Ubuntu instance. Flask is `Running on http://0.0.0.0:8080/` and the only **Inbound** rule I have (apart from ssh) is this: `Protocol: TCP, Port Range: 8080, Source: 0.0.0.0/0`. Perhaps check if the security group in question is assigned to your EC2 instance?

Comment: Yep, the correct security group is assigned as well :(

Comment: What kind of OS are you running on the instance? Is there another firewall running there perhaps? Can you spin up a fresh instance for testing purposes?

Comment: Amazon Linux 2 AMI. I doubt there's another firewall. I'll try spinning up a new instance.

Comment: Same thing again: launched amazon linux 2 instance, yum install python 3, ran flask on http://0.0.0.0:8080, opened up this port in aws security group with an inbound rule. After that I was able to successfully connect with curl.

Comment: Im Having the same problem running a dotnet web app on port 7070? Any luck?
thanks!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62491794/dotnet-app-on-ec2-linux-port-7070-not-accessible?noredirect=1#comment110517110_62491794

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone is having this problem too, make sure that you have a Gateway configured

Comment: I can't edit my message but this is the full text "Just in case anyone is having this problem too, make sure that you have a Gateway configured with your subnet and not a NAT on AWS."