# Dotnet app on EC2 Linux port 7070 not accessible

Tags: amazon-web-services, port

[image]can't connect to an dotnet app running in an aws EC2 instance on port 7070
I've added the port to the security group and when I check if the port is open (netstat -ntlp) I get the output below:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7070          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      27021/dotnet
```

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: can you please attach the security group screenshot and I guess you are using `http://public_ip_ec2:7070/` for accessing your service?

Comment: Hello Nitesh,
Thank you for looking into this, I've attached the security group screenshot, and yes for using http://public_ip_ec2:7070/

Comment: share the result for curl http://private_ip_ec2:7070/ ?

Comment: @NiteshSharma
curl: (7) Failed to connect to PrivateIp port 7070: Connection refused

Comment: As per this, it's clear that it's not an issue with EC2 it is related to your application server which application server you are using? and Have you configured for port ?

Comment: I believe it's MySql, What you mean by if I have configured for port

Comment: MySQL is not your application server it should be like apache.  your service is microservice?

Comment: Is the DotNET application a web app? This is running on a Windows server, or Linux? From inside the server can you connect to `127.0.0.1:7070`?

Comment: Hello Mark, Yes it is and i'm able to connect to the 127.0.0.1:7070 through the terminal and its running fine using curl 127.0.0.1:7070

Comment: do your project have any lauch.settings if so then change your launch.settings file `{
  "iisSettings": {
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://*:7070"
    }
  },`

Comment: Thanks Nitesh, will do and will let you know the outcome :)

Comment: I did, but unfortunately still the same issue. BTW im running on ubuntu (Linux) if this will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by downloading nginx to my EC2 instance
(https://gist.github.com/soheilhy/8b94347ff8336d971ad0) and forwarding my custom port to port 80

Hopefully this will help!