# How do I deploy my Python Flask dev app so other devices across the network (Wifi) can also access it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, web-hosting

This is my app.py file:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

app.run(host = '192.168.2.18', debug=False)
```

I've used the netstat command in Windows and that's how I know to use '192.168.2.18' When I run the file, it appears to run on port 5000

Please see pic below:

[image: App runs!]

However, when I try to access this url from another device over the network, I don't see it. I only see it on my machine.

I've tried various solutions most notably from this popular thread:

[Configure Flask dev server to be visible across the network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023052/configure-flask-dev-server-to-be-visible-across-the-network)

Answer (score 0):

If you update the `host` ip in your code to `0.0.0.0`, then your app will start listening all the public IPs.

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

You can read [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#a-minimal-application) in the flask docs.

Now for someone to access your page, they have to navigate to this url -

http://your.machine.ip:5000/

You can also give any specific port you want your application to run at, lets say 4000 (default port is 5000)

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=4000)
```

You can even give your machine name in place of your machine ip in the url, just incase your ip is not static.

Answer (score 0):

I tell you a secret, run:

```
python3 -m http.server
```

and the directory in which you are will be available through all the network.
In this example I'm visiting my `Pictures` folder and as you can see is available at `http://0.0.0.0:8000/`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned, you already tried the solutions from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7023052/11745574), here's something I think you can try because I was facing this same problem once and this is what I was missing, and it's overlooked a lot of times.
If you are a Windows user, check your Network and sharing settings, and turn it ON for sharing on a private network. Something like this:

[image]

Also, make sure your IP address in the code below is correct (because IP address changes all the time when you connect your laptop/computer over Wi-Fi), so check the current IP by running `ipconfig` in cmd right before running your code, not the one you wrote a week ago.

Few changes in the code:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000)   //doesn't work for me
    app.run(host='192.168.2.18', port=5000)
```

And finally, run your code with `flask run -h 192.168.X.X`, in the screenshot you shared, you entered `flask run --host 192.168.X.X`, I m not sure why, but --h doesn't work for me.
And, I hope you also check you are entering the address properly, like http://192.168.2.18:5000, not https.
Sometimes silly stuff can get in the way too :|