# running flask server on localhost error connection refused

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to run a flask app on my local machine but in my browsers I get error connection refused messages and sometimes i get the message in my terminal. The app did successfully create my table but I cannot view it in my browser. for host I have tried, localhost, 0.0.0.0 and 127.0.0.1 and for ports I have tried 5000, 8000, 8080, 8002 and I get the same error every time. I do have a VPN installed on my machine but it is turned off and I did a fresh restart without ever running the application and I still get the error. What is going wrong here?

I'm running windows 10 and using a vagrant virtual box running ubuntu 16 uaing gitbash. I have an ipVanish application on my computer for a VPN but the vpn is turned off and I did a fresh restart without opening the application and am still having the problem

This is my code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:F00tBall@127.0.0.1:5432/example'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Person(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'persons'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)

db.create_all()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    person = Person.query.first()
    return 'Hello ' + person.name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.secret_key = 'super_secret_key'
    app.debug = True
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(host= '127.0.0.1', port=port)
```

i've also tried

```
app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000)
```

i ran 
`

```
sudo ufw allow 5000
```

but that didn't seem to do anything.

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Flask inside of a VM, 'localhost' means local to the VM. Your browser is likely outside the VM, and therefore not local. Instead of 127.0.0.1, use 0.0.0.0

Try it again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using host=0.0.0.0.

I understand this causes flask serve on the IP address address of the machine that is running it. Then connect to that IP address on port 5000?

[Configure Flask dev server to be visible across the network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023052/configure-flask-dev-server-to-be-visible-across-the-network)