# Flask access from different devices

Tags: html, flask, web-applications

Is there a way to generate a specific IP address or make a specific site of flask http://127.0.0.1:5000/ site which runs locally, to access the web-app made using flask from different device as by default it runs locally and under http://127.0.0.1:5000/ but,i want to access it from different devices.If,there's a way please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

refer first to this [doc](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#a-minimal-application) (section **Externally Visible Server**) on how to expose your local `Flask` app to make it accessible from **trusted** devices in your network for **testing purposes**.

```
$(venv) flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```

or in your `app.py`

```
from flask import Flask
[..]
app = Flask(__name__)
[..]
if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, debug=True)
```

and then :

```
$(venv) python app.py
```

but if it happens and you got this error `dial tcp 0.0.0.0:5000: connect: connection refused` then try to use the local ip address (`192.168.x.y` instead of `0.0.0.0`) of the machine hosting your `Flask` app. you may find this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023052/configure-flask-dev-server-to-be-visible-across-the-network/7027113) usefull

Answer (score 1):

You can access your server on devices in the same Network / Wifi with your private IP address and the port.
On Mac OS `option + click` on Wifi in your Taskbar.

On linux:
`> ifconfig`

Comment: is this possible in any way to just copy the url of site and send it to my friend and it is available to him there by using url in flask ,That means a specific url/website related to that page without using my own device address

Comment: you can take your public IP of your ISP, but consider, that usually these IPs are dynamically changing

Answer (score 1):

- Instead of localhost (127.0.0.1), you need to type your router's public IP. If you do not already know it, you can retrieve it by typing `ipconfig` (for Windows) or `ifconfig` (for Linux) in the command line.
- You also need to disable your firewall or add an inbound rule for the port used by your server (e.g. 5000).

Comment: is this possible in any way to just copy the url of site and send it to my friend and it is available to him there by using url in flask ,That means a specific url/website related to that page without using my own device address

Comment: You need to forward the inbound traffic to the required port. This can be done from the settings found on your router's interface (usually accessed on 192.168.1.1). Be aware that some ISPs are blocking spesific ports, so try to use a not well-known port.