# flask won't run outside of localhost

Tags: python, flask, ip-address, cs50

I'm sorry this question has been asked before and answered.

The flask app does not serve outside of the local host network.

This is what I've tried before.

[ipconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9REd0.png)

What I've Tried

1. Inbound rule change to allow port 5000.
2. Changing port to 80 and then to 33 to test
3. set host to 0.0.0.0
4. Tried all with app.run(host=) method and cmd line interface

is it something I'm not seeing yet. Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Configure Flask dev server to be visible across the network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023052/configure-flask-dev-server-to-be-visible-across-the-network)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need something like `ngrok` to transfer outside connection to your localhost. Say you are running `flask` at `8080`. Then to access it you'll need ngrok and the command will be `ngrok http 8080`. This will give another address which can be used to access flask on your localhost. Also, there are many alternates to this method, but ngrok is quick and easy.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the vague answer but I cant help much without actually looking at the code. But have you tried running it on an apache server, I did that for a small project in my home and it worked alright.

This is the resource I found useful myself: https://dev.to/willmvs/flask-deployment-on-windows-139b