# Flask OpenCV send video stream to extrenal HTML Page

Tags: opencv, flask, computer-vision, rtsp, ip-camera

I would like to ask a question regarding the use of flask in the management of the video stream:
1-> I recover the video stream from an Ip camera with the rtsp protocol
2-> with Flask I display the video but in my browser in localHsot

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
import cv2

app = Flask(__name__)

camera = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://--:--@ipAdress/media.amp")


def gen_frames():
    while True:
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        success, frame = camera.read()
        #cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        print("success-------",success)
        if not success:
            break
        else:
            ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
            frame = buffer.tobytes()
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                   b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')


@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    #Video streaming route. Put this in the src attribute of an img tag
    return Response(gen_frames(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')


@app.route('/')
def index():
    """Video streaming home page."""
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I would like to know please, is it possible to do the display not in locahost http://127.0.0.1:5000  but to send it to an external HTML page

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a parameter to your `app.run()`. By default it runs on localhost, change it to `app.run(host= '0.0.0.0')` to run on all your machine's IP addresses. `0.0.0.0` is a special value, you'll need to navigate to the actual IP address.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host= '0.0.0.0',debug=True)
```

Then a Client Browser need your machine IP and your open port to navigate and view the Stream

```
http://your-machine-ip:5000
```

So the mechanism is that your machine create a file index.html  and serve it  when a external Browser request the address
`http://your-machine-ip:5000`

put your index.html  in folder `templates/index.html`

More details here : [Configure Flask dev server to be visible across the network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023052/configure-flask-dev-server-to-be-visible-across-the-network)

I think you need  `camera.release()` also.