# Flask connection refused on same machine using Angular

Tags: python, angular, azure, flask, cors

I have a Flask server that is running in an Azure VM (Ubuntu 20.04) that is supposed to be run on `http://127.0.0.1:5000` and an Angular app that serves as a frontend and hosts `0.0.0.0/80`. The Angular app is supposed to send GET/POST requests to the Flask server, but when I try to do so I get the following error [1].

I have CORS enabled for all domains on all routes in Flask.
And if I send the request using wget it works perfectly fine.

Here's how I'm sending my request from Angular:

```
this.http.post<ILoginResponse>('http://127.0.0.1:5000/login', {username: un, password: pswrd}).subscribe(data => {
      this.loginResponse.success = data.success;
      this.loginResponse.teamID = data.teamID;
    })
```

With ILoginResponse being:

```
export interface ILoginResponse{
  success: boolean;
  teamID: string;
}
```

I have set rules in the Azure portal to allow connections on port 5000 and unlocked the port in the firewall in the VM itself. Running Flask with `--host 0.0.0.0` does not help either.

Any idea of what could help or which direction I could look in?

[1]

````
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:2845
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:385
onScheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:272
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:378
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:210
scheduleMacroTask @ zone-evergreen.js:233
scheduleMacroTaskWithCurrentZone @ zone-evergreen.js:1134
(anonymous) @ zone-evergreen.js:2878
proto.<computed> @ zone-evergreen.js:1449
(anonymous) @ http.js:1785
_trySubscribe @ Observable.js:42
subscribe @ Observable.js:28
innerSubscribe @ innerSubscribe.js:67
_innerSub @ mergeMap.js:57
_tryNext @ mergeMap.js:51
_next @ mergeMap.js:34
next @ Subscriber.js:49
(anonymous) @ subscribeToArray.js:3
_trySubscribe @ Observable.js:42
subscribe @ Observable.js:28
call @ mergeMap.js:19
subscribe @ Observable.js:23
call @ filter.js:13
subscribe @ Observable.js:23
call @ map.js:16
subscribe @ Observable.js:23
checkCredentials @ login.component.ts:63
login @ login.component.ts:44
LoginComponent_Template_form_ngSubmit_6_listener @ login.component.html:12
executeListenerWithErrorHandling @ core.js:14994
wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault @ core.js:15029
schedulerFn @ core.js:25687
__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:183
next @ Subscriber.js:122
_next @ Subscriber.js:72
next @ Subscriber.js:49
next @ Subject.js:39
emit @ core.js:25656
onSubmit @ forms.js:5719
FormGroupDirective_submit_HostBindingHandler @ forms.js:5774
executeListenerWithErrorHandling @ core.js:14994
wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault @ core.js:15029
(anonymous) @ platform-browser.js:582
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:399
onInvokeTask @ core.js:28289
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:398
runTask @ zone-evergreen.js:167
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:480
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:1621
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone-evergreen.js:1647
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: 'Unknown Error', url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/login', ok: false, …}
error: ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: 'error', …}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
message: "Http failure response for http://127.0.0.1:5000/login: 0 Unknown Error"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"
url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/login"
[[Prototype]]: HttpResponseBase
constructor: class HttpErrorResponse
[[Prototype]]: Object```
````

Comment: address `127.0.0.1` can assess only programs which run on the same computer but `Angular` runs in user's browser so it runs on user's computer so using `127.0.0.1` it tries to access user's computer, not server with Flask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [furas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1832058/furas). Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

Address `127.0.0.1` can assess only programs which run on the same computer but Angular runs in the user's browser so it runs on user's computer so using `127.0.0.1` it tries to access user's computer, not the server with Flask.

> Running Flask with --host 0.0.0.0 does not help either.

You can refer to the answer by [nwillo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56438755/15969115) to run the flask app on IPv4 address

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer. It turned out that the solution was improper CORS headers on the Angular side (although I was told they were set correctly) and using `0.0.0.0`