# continuous error of flask app after deploying to the web | "not found" shown on the link on which website is hosted

Tags: python, flask, web, deployment

my website after I have deployed it via GitHub on some service providers does not shows up on the internet and I think there's some problem in the code
I have tried different service providers there is no error in their log so its definitely not the service provider and must be the code

[here](https://github.com/aaditgarg17/error) is the clone of repo

Comment: Try to give the host parameter to app.run() See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023052/configure-flask-dev-server-to-be-visible-across-the-network

Comment: thank you for your suggestion but can you elaborate it more specifically like to what I should change the parameter

Comment: [UPDATE][george] I tried it to but the error's still intact

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem have been resolved the problem was that, that I need to add:

`If __name__=="__main__":`

`app.run()`

To run the app