# Flask Web App Runs Locally but Times Out on iPhone - How to Access from Mobile Device?

Tags: python, flask, networking

I am new to Flask and created a basic webpage with some buttons. The eventual goal is to use the webpage from my phone (iphone if that matters). The Flask App runs on my local IP address fine, but when I try putting in http://[my ipv4 address]:5000 into my phone's web browser it loads until it times out. I am on the same network.

Running this code gives no errors, and I can access the webpage fine from my computer:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=  'templates', static_folder= 'static_files')

@app.route('/')
def controller():
    return render_template("index.html")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host= '0.0.0.0', port= 5000, debug=True)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023052/configure-flask-dev-server-to-be-visible-across-the-network

Comment: No, I believe I have attempted all these suggestions with no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

The problem was that windows firewall defender was blocking the python executable. I resolved the issue by going to "windows defender firewall" in the search, then advanced settings, then "inbound rules" and disabling python being blocked by clicking "disable" on the right tool bar (under actions).
[python being blocked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ankPm.png)

Answer (score 0):

Are you on windows, by chance? If so, you likely need to allow inbound connections on port 5000. The following would need to be run from an administrator prompt. Alternatively, you could use the *GUI*.

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="TCP Port 5000" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=5000
```

You definitely overcame the most common issue by including *host* in your code in this line:
`app.run(host= '0.0.0.0', port= 5000, debug=True)`. In fact, when you run your python script, a good check is that the terminal tells you that the application is available at `http://127.0.0.1:5000` **and** at `http://<ipaddress>:5000`. If this all looks good, I would suspect a firewall issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am on windows, and I do get that output. I ran the command to allow connections, but I am still unable to connect.