Getting Nginx 502 Bad Gateway after deploying Flask API to Elastic Beanstalk |111: Connection refused while connecting to upstream
I'm really new into servers and stepping from development into production and lately I've had some errors while deploying a Flask API to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I "successfully" deployed my API through EB CLI as it said so, but when I open the domain, it only says "502 Bad Gateway - nginx".
I downloaded the logs, and I'm pretty concerned about what nginx's error.log says:
connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.41.209, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "172.31.22.xxx"
I thought the process was pretty straightforward when it comes to deploying to EB, but I've tried to solve this problem and I haven't been able. My API runs perfectly in development; I've tested it a lot of times in localhost at default port, but now in deployment it no longer works. So I think it's more of a reverse-proxy-related problem, but I don't know much about this, so I'd appreciate so much your help. I've used Windows the whole time and virtually every info out there is Linux-related, so I'm very limited to it.
I'm going to paste a fragment of web.stdout.log, which looks like to show some errors related to Gunicorn:
Apr 27 23:44:18 ip-172-31-22-xxx web[2165]: [2024-04-27 23:44:18 +0000] [2165] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 22.0.0

Apr 27 23:44:18 ip-172-31-22-xxx web[2165]: [2024-04-27 23:44:18 +0000] [2165] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (2165)

Apr 27 23:44:18 ip-172-31-22-xxx web[2165]: [2024-04-27 23:44:18 +0000] [2165] [INFO] Using worker: gthread

Apr 27 23:44:18 ip-172-31-22-xxx web[2197]: [2024-04-27 23:44:18 +0000] [2197] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2197

Apr 27 23:44:18 ip-172-31-22-xxx web[2197]: [2024-04-27 23:44:18 +0000] [2197] [ERROR] Exception in worker process

Apr 27 23:44:18 ip-172-31-22-xxx web[2197]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Apr 27 23:44:18 ip-172-31-22-xxx web[2197]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 609, in spawn_worker

Please help!
Within my limited knowledge of servers, deploying, AWS, I've tried to find an error with the way the API interacts with server but I haven't get so far yet, so I expect someone who knows about this and is willing to help me, may tell me what to fix and how to do it (what tools needed, commands, etc.) in order to solve this problem. Thanks a lot beforehand.

It seems the API is listening to localhost(127.0.0.1). You have to update the FAST API to listen on 0.0.0.0:8000 instead of 127.0.0.1:8000. After updating the configuration, restart the server.

Hi, Aravindan. I appreciate so much your answer. Could you please tell me how to do so? I'm not really into this and I lack of knowledge to do what you suggest. Do I have to modify my Python Flask API file or it's more related to the server's config through AWS EB, and it needs to be modified with a SSH client or something? Thank you so much.

It is not related to Elastic Beanstalk, You have to update your Application main file or the cmd you use to run the Flask App. Go through this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023052/configure-flask-dev-server-to-be-visible-across-the-network

Hi, Aravindan. The solution was very related to where you pointed me! This is a bit ashaming actually but I didn't name my API file as application.py, so it wasn't even loading and, thus the port was not accessed. Thanks for answering! Looking at the information you sent, I could get to the answer. Have a nice day, Sir.

The solution was pretty simple actually. I didn't have to set environment properties, nor had to change the process default port neither. I didn't realize my API filename was not application.py, so it wasn't being loaded as a Flask API (as per my understanding), and thus the port wasn't being accessed. Changing the name resolved the problem! Make sure to name your API file application.py.
